# MLE estimation of parameters, converting normalized observations to integers and back

Tags: optimization, parametric, parameter-estimation

I am fitting a model's parameters to grouped data by maximizing the likelihood equation:

$L(\theta)=N!\prod_{i=1}^{G}\frac{p_i(\theta)^{n_i}}{n_i!}$

$\theta$ is the vector of parameters.  $n_i$ is the number of observations in group i.  That is, $n_i=x_i-x_{i-1}$ where $x_i$ is an individual observation.  $N$ is the total number of observations ($N=\sum_{i}n_i$).  $G$ is the number of groups.

And $p_i(\theta)=F(x_i;\theta)-F(x_{i-1};\theta)$, where $F(x_i;\theta)$ is the distribution function I am trying to fit to the data.

My problem is that the observations are normalized (they are percentiles).  So $0<n_i<1$, when I need integers for the factorials.  Multiplying $N$ and $n_i$ by 100 and rounding allows me to run the equation in matlab, but then I am not sure what to do with the output in order to convert it back to 1/100 scale.  Appreciate some advice.  Thanks.